# Do I need to close file again after with open file as fp closed file in python

Tags: python

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    do something
fp.close()
```

I know with open as will call **exit** which will call close method to close the opened file. But I saw a lot of people still tried to close the file again, python does not bother to close a closed file? which is the best practice or the most safe way when you use a file by with as?

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely should not call `fp.close()` after the end of the `with` block, which closes it automatically.  That code you show is simply broken.  It should be:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    do something
```

Comment: what if he put the fp.close() statement inside the with block. Is that right to close the file? just curious.

Comment: It would simply close the file earlier than the point in time when the `with` block is exited. It is not an error to call `.close()` on a closed file.

Comment: @Bhansa: Generally you should not call `close()` explicitly at all if you're using `with`.

Comment: as I said python did not bother you try to close a closed file again, which is very interesting to me. you still can refer to fp after with open block called exit method?